# How to pass argument input to a self-defined function in R?

Tags: r, function, input, ggplot2, arguments

I made a self-defined plottest function as this:

```
plottest<-function(dataframe, var1){

  ggplot(dataframe)+geom_point(aes(x=T, y=var1))

}
```

I wish I could pass a dataframe and a column name to it so I can repeated plot different columns.

```
df <- data.frame(T=(1:10), y1=(21:30), y2=(51:60), y3 = (61:70))
```

But when I do:

```
library(ggplot2)    
plottest(df, y1)
```

Error message shows up saying:object 'var1' not found.

What should I do to make this work??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df <- data.frame(T=(1:10), y1=(21:30), y2=(51:60), y3 = (61:70))

plottest<-function(dataframe, var1){
  ggplot(dataframe, aes_string(x='T', y=var1))+geom_point()
}

plottest(df, 'y1')
```

It would be even cleaner to fix the abcissa in the function argument as default parameter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make you original function work with a simple added line (and I added the ylab() call to prevent the plot from always using "y" as the ylab.

```
plottest<-function(dataframe, var1){
    y <- substitute(var1)
   ggplot(dataframe)+geom_point(aes(x=T, y=y)) + ylab(y) 
 }
 library(ggplot2)    
 plottest(df, y1)
```